# How do you determine these coefficients experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, rotational-kinematics, home-experiment, data-analysis

So in our lab today my friend and I had to examine the time it takes for cylinders to roll down an incline.

We managed to find an ansatz on the following form after some work:

$$ t = c(c_1 + x^{c_2})^{c_3}*s/\sqrt{hg} $$

Where $x$ constitutes the ratio between the inner and outer diameter of the cylinder.

Using logaritms the problem can be reduced to:

$\ln(t) = c_3\ln(c_1+x^{c_2}) + \ln(c\sqrt(hg))$

If we choose to not use $c$ in our ansatz, and with 3 data points (where we measured the time for different ratios x), we manage to find $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ with fairly good precision if compared to the theoretical formula by data fitting through curve - fit in Python.However, as soon as we use $c$ in our ansatz, there's no way to actually find $c$ through our Python program.

We decided to measure the time once again but with 6 data points, and once again, Python wrote out an error that it couldn't find the optimal coefficients. We suspect that the x - ratio's where fairly similar and that this is the cause for not being able to find the coefficients. However, we also didn't have any other ratio's to test with.

With the theoretical expression for the time, it's found that $c = 1$, however, we have to show this through our experiments, and not just assume that's the case. We don't really know how to simplify the expression further, in so that our Python program successfully can manage to fit the data points to the second formula described above. Nor do we know how to show that $c=1$ in our experiment.

Maybe there's some better program out there that can fit the second equation to these 6 data points, or maybe there's some algebraic way to make $c$ vanish. I hope you can provide with a small tip that may help us further in this experiment. I'd be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Why use an Ansatz when an analytical solution  is actually KNOWN?

Comment: Because we can't use the analytical to decude our result according to our teacher, everything has to be done through experimental data :/

Comment: Your teacher needs immediate SACKING. You can use empiricism to prove the analytical solution is in fact correct. Using wild-eyed models like your 'Ansatz' is sheer folly! You can tell him that from me.

Comment: Lol, I'll make sure to tell him dont you worry :)

Answer (score 0):

SciPy curvefit should be used for non-linear fittting. However as you realized yourself it is hard for this fitting method to converge for many variable and complicated functions in general.

For this reason and from the believe that real physics is always *beautiful* and *simple* it makes sense to go with the most trivial function which might be able to describe your data - You guess this Ansatz from your general knowledge about functions and from your data.

Then you evaluate how good the fit is. If it is bad, try a more complicated function. Continue until you are satisfied. Then try to come up with theoretical arguments supporting this functional form. Your function seems overly complicated IMO to begin with.

As @Gert points out it is somewhat stupid if you do know the real solution already, but it can be somewhat helpful to guess functional forms from real world data if the theory is unknown to you.